# Where should async task be executed in fragment to update the view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous

I want to set a adapter view in fragment which gets its data from webservice. Where should I execute the async task so that I don't get the lag in view loading?
I tried it in onAttach and onCreateview but its not working as expected?                                                                                               `

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("oncreateview","oncreateview");
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_calendar_view, container, false);
      _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String j="{\"userId\":\"733894\",\"startDate\":\"24-04-2016\",\"endDate\":\"25-04-2016\"}";
        new TimeSheetTask(getActivity(),j) {

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute( String result ) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);
                gson = new Gson();
                timesheet = gson.fromJson(result, Timesheet.class);
                if (timesheet != null) {


                    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(MyCalendarFragment.this,
                            R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year, timesheet.getTimeSheetList());
                    calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);


                }
            }
        }.execute();



        prevMonth = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
        prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        currentMonth = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));

        nextMonth = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
        nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        calendarView = (GridView) root.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        if (timesheet != null) {


            adapter = new GridCellAdapter(MyCalendarFragment.this,
                    R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year, timesheet.getTimeSheetList());
            calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        return root;
    }`
```

Comment: Please provide some code :).

Comment: onPostExecute is executed on main thread, you should deserialize your JSON onBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Call the web service in onActivityCreated method and then update your views

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```
 new TimeSheetTask<String, String, String>() {
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

 String j="{\"userId\":\"733894\",\"startDate\":\"24-04-2016\",\"endDate\":\"25-04-2016\"}";
 return j;
       }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( String result ) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            gson = new Gson();
            timesheet = gson.fromJson(result, Timesheet.class);
            if (timesheet != null) {


                adapter = new GridCellAdapter(MyCalendarFragment.this,
                        R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year, timesheet.getTimeSheetList());
                calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

If you want to show some loading bar also then you can call onPreExecute() method.

Hope this help you.